# add the sum of a variable in a .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm .each()'ing over some dom nodes and extracting their values after I parseFloat through them.

In the .each, i'm attempting to use some math to add the sum of the output variable together.

How does one do that?

see what i'm talking about here:

http://jsfiddle.net/LpHbk/1/

Please use your console to see what the .each() is dropping in the dom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add numbers, *somewhere* [you're going to have to use `+`](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif).

```
var re = /.*\$/g;
var total = 0;

$("#dropDowns select option:selected").each(function() {
    var ourValue = $(this).text();
    var basePrice = re.test(ourValue) ? parseFloat(ourValue.replace(re, ''), 10) : 0;
    total += basePrice;
});

$("#finalValue").text("$" + total);
```

Also, DRY up that code! http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/uhUHt

Comment: Use the `+ operator`? You should totally drop that and try JQuery. Oh wait.

Answer (score 1):

I would be sure to make the selector more specific so as to only include the `select` elements that you actually want included.

```
$("select").on("change", function(){
  var price = 0;
  $("select option:selected").each(function(){
    price += parseInt( this.value.match( /\$(\d+\.\d+)/ )[1] , 10 );
  });
  alert( '$' + price.toFixed(2) );
})
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/amubew/2/edit